# Loading a single pixel from an image without loading the entire image

Tags: image

I want to load a single pixel from a large satellite image for an operation. Loading the entire image is a performance concern, so I want to create a solution that only loads the required pixel. Would this even be possible? Preferred technologies are .NET and shell scripting, though any appropriate technologies which can solve this problem are welcome. I also have control over the creation of the image file, so other file formats, etc. are possible.

Comment: Yes, it's conceivably possible at least with some uncompressed image formats, e.g. 24 or 32 bit RGB-mapped BMP, but you'll probably have to parse the headers manually to figure out where in the file the pixel is located. How do you know which pixel to load?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yeah that sounds like a good approach. The pixel location will correspond to a lat/long position provided by a function parameter.